# How to serve an already coded html page in a WP page, to assign a simpler url

Tags: customization, pages

Is it possible to use WordPress to serve up a hard coded page that already exists? The goal is that we want to make some simple shorter urls but not have a huge mess in the root directory of our website.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly. You would be just bypassing wordpress all together right?

There is nothing to keep you from putting files in your web directory and then navigating to "http://yoursite.com/test.html".  To keep from making  a mess of your root directory I'd recomend putting them into a folder so your path would look more like "http://yoursite.com/secondsite/index.html"

Are you wanting to Wordpress to interact with these files, or are they essentially a stand alone website?

Answer (score 0):

The person I'm helping won't use folders, and wants simple file names. I've tried convincing them to use a nice folder structure, but they won't do that. They "speak" the url on audios, radio, etc. and want super easy urls. Whether we use html in the root or folders with index.html inside, it will still end up being thousands of files or folders in the root.

I know with a WP site, the "mess" is kind of hidden, and it is a lot easier to file manage even if they keep all urls simple like:

http://example.com/page-1

I'm not really a coder, so I'm just kind of trying to come up with some sort of solution, though I don't know if what I'm asking is possible, or even wise.